# Redis, expiring array items

Tags: redis

I'm trying to use Redis for preventing excessive access to a website, here's a plan, I'd have an array of data

> IP => (0 => http://, 1 => http://)

However what I need to do is to set an EXPIRE tag for each one of those items, i've looked into sets, hashes and many other, however I can't seem to find a way. I was told by server support that it's possible but i'm way too new to redis.

I've found the following example on their website

```
RPUSH pagewviews.user:<userid> http://.....
EXPIRE pagewviews.user:<userid> 60
```

However i'd need to know the key, which I can't seem to get or find a way to get. I'm using predis to work with redis. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

The `userid` comes from your app, not from Redis. It can be:

- a logical, unique user name (if users authenticate on your site)
- some sort of unique ID assigned to every user and persisted in a cookie (disadvantage: users can delete cookies)
- a client IP address (disadvantage: multiple users might use the same IP address from a variety of reasons).

Comment: @Saulius has this helped you?